# Parameter value [100] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, createquery

I am facing weird problem in one query

```
select * from sbill.act_sub_t where (act_sub_t.unsub_dt - 
act_sub_t.sub_dt) < 100;
```

Using this query i am getting result in oracle sql developer tool but facing below issue with java.

```
 Parameter value [100] did not match expected type 
 [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]
```

Below is the java code

```
  Query query1 = entityManager.createQuery("select * from ActSubT 
  where (ActSubT.unsub_dt - ActSubT.sub_dt) <:days").setParameter("days", 
   100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with `TO_DATE()`

```
select * from sbill.act_sub_t 
where (TO_DATE(act_sub_t.unsub_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE(act_sub_t.sub_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) < 100;
```

Comment: Yes i have tried with toDate , its working now but earlier when  i was running this query from sql developer then 10 records were coming but now with toDate 8 records are coming ..  i am checking why this happening.

Comment: As of now my application is using oracle db  but later on it will use mysql as well. so after that this solution will not work as mysql doesn't support  "TO_DATE"   function.
Any solution with mysql ?

Comment: @HarishBagora The question asked for Oracle, so if the answer is helped to solve your issue, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043). For MySQL related, you can ask a new question with the possible query you have and what you tried for MySQL.

Comment: okay... accepted , i will ask new question for that thanks :)

Comment: For MySQL, can you try with [DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php). So something like `select * from sbill.act_sub_t 
where DATEDIFF(act_sub_t.unsub_dt, act_sub_t.sub_dt) < 100;`

Comment: Do we have something like that which is common for both oracle and mysql  ?  
As of now my application support oracle DB but in future if any other customer wants MySQL support then i will migrate it in to the MySQL . so i want such a code in my application which  support  both the DB.

Comment: @HarishBagora I'm not aware such a method available to support Oracle and MySQL.